# want to add to buttons on top of every view in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I want to add two buttons of width 133 px and 150 px each and 28 px in height on top of every view in my iPhone app. Only the view below this button bar will change, but when navigation occurs (push pop operation), I want this bar also to slide with the remaining view.
basically, i want a bar containing 2 buttons to be present in ever screen of the app. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Are you using `UINavigationController` with a navigation bar on top and want to have your buttons below the bar or do you want to have your buttons in the navigation bar?

Comment: No, i am using navigation bar, but it is hidden in all screens, so this bar will be there instead

Comment: Why are you doing this? Surely you get all the functionality you want in a navigation bar?

Comment: my buttons are long in width so they cannot be added in navigation bar, thats why. If you have some suggestion on how to add two long buttons at left and right corners (no titleView), then please help. Thanks

Comment: set the titleView to nil to remove the title then add a leftBarButtonItem and a rightBarButtonItem. If you'd like me to expand on this I can.

Comment: Will it take UIbarButtonItem of any width? I do not want my buttons to be clipped off or be reduced in width. Thanks for replying

Comment: see my edit on my answer. it will take a button of any width, as long as it fits. You can also `initWithCustomView` or `initWithImage` which may also help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd be best off writing a subclass of UIViewController (for instance call it `CustomUIViewController`).

in the viewDidLoad method of this class you can add the view as appropriate eg:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIView *bar = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,28)] autorelease];
    UIButton *buttonOne = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    // etc...
    [bar addSubview:buttonOne];
    UIButton *buttonTwo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    // etc...
    [bar addSubview:buttonTwo];

    [self.view insertSubview:bar atIndex:0];
}
```

That should work (as long as you remember to call `[super viewDidLoad]` in all your classes.

Now you just have to make sure you're subclassing CustomUIViewController instead of UIViewController in your view controllers.

**Edit**

To get the navigation bar option to work do this:

```
    UIBarButtonItem *cancel = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancelsdkjfnsdjfhksdjfhks" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cancel:)] autorelease];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:cancel];
    UIBarButtonItem *send = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Senddsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(send:)] autorelease];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:send];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this surely is one possibility, but can you provide me a solution on how to add long buttons as UIBarButtonItems on UINavigationBar

Comment: I tried this approach in navigationBar by initWithCustomView: uibutton since I have image for button and not title. this is not working. The navigationBar is blank

Comment: I got it working, you have to init a button with target, action set and set the frame of button with origin as 0,0. then initialize barButton with initWithCustomView:button. Thanks for showing the direction.

Answer (score -1):

We'll start by laying out a view containing buttons. In Xcode, create a new View-based iPhone application, and call it "GradientButtons" (or whatever you want). Double-click the GradientButtonsViewController.xib resource to open it in Interface Builder.

Drag a UIButton control from the library onto the view. Set its properties like this:

```
* Change the type to "Custom"
* Set the title to "Gray"
* Change the text color to white
* Change the background color to gray
```

Comment: you didn't got my question. I want to add a bar containing two buttons as its subview. Now this bar should be present in Every view/screen of the app. Please have a look at the question